# Correct encoding to use to read Italian characters from a text file

Tags: c#, .net, multilingual

I'm having some problems when trying to do read Italian text from a file using C#.

```
//actual text in the file - può darsi che tu riesca

string sampleItalianText = "può";

string contents = File.ReadAllText(filepath);
bool hasMatch = contents.Contains(sampleItalianText);

//hasMatch is always false because contents has a strange symbol in place of ò
```

I tried

```
File.ReadAllText(filepath, Encoding.GetEncoding(1144);  //IBM EBCDIC (Italy-Euro)
```

but no luck so far.

Eventually, when there is a match, I have to write out the translated text (which is in some other language) back to the same file as well.

What is the right encoding to use to get around this issue? Or Is there any methods I could use other than `ReadAllText()`?

Comment: Have you tried using `Encoding.UTF8`?

Comment: If its been saved as ANSI `Encoding.Default`

Comment: Tried both UTF8 and UTF-16. Didn't work.

Comment: Encoding.Default Worked..! Thanks.

Comment: FYI its bound to the machine setup so wont necessarily be portable

Comment: Note that Encoding.Default is the operating system's current ANSI page.  If you want your code to be independent of the OS locale, you're better off explicitly specifying the Encoding - e.g. `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)` or `Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1252")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to know the encoding before reading the file. [`File.ReadAllText(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms143368) will attempt to detect the encoding, which is not at all reliable. If you can, read and write UTF-8, since everything that takes a default in .NET will use UTF-8, and you will avoid conversion issues between systems that use different languages.

The next most popular encoding on Western systems is Windows-1252, so usually, if a file is not encoded as UTF-8, it's encoded as Windows-1252. You can also use `Encoding.Default` to read files, if you know they were created locally, but please don't use it to write files.